# dynamically calling procedure in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I want to call procedure whose name has been entered by the user. How can I do it?

For example: I want to call `procedure1` in `pocedure2`

```
create or replace procedure procedure1(
  a in number,
  b in number
  cv_1 out sys_refcursor
)
as
begin
  ....//doin something
end;
```

procedure2:

```
create or replace procedure procedure2 (
   procedure1name in varchar2,
   a in number,
   b in number,
   cv_1 out sys_refcursor
)
as
begin
   ....//call procedure1 and return cv_1
end;
```

Comment: You can do it using dynamic SQL. Go and search in Oracle Docs for further details.

Comment: As @Rachcha says, you'll need to use dynamic SQL.  Do you know at compile time the signature of `procedure1`?  Do you know at compile time how to map the parameters that are passed to `procedure2` to the call to `procedure1`?

Answer (score 3):

To be able to do that you need to use `execute immediate`(native dynamic SQL) statement because, as the procedure name is being entered by a user and passed in as a `varchar2` parameter to an another procedure, there is no way to tell what the name of a procedure is at compile time. So, in your second procedure, to execute procedure #1 which name is passed in as a `varchar2` parameter,  you could do the following:

```
execute immediate 'begin ' || procedure1name || '(:p1, :p2, :p3); end;'
  using in a, b, out cv_1;
```

[**Find out more**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/dynamic.htm#i13130) about native dynamic SQL

Comment: @Shanku In the example above bind variables(`(:p1, :p2, :p3)`) are used to pass in `IN` and `OUT` parameters to the `procedure1name` procedure using `USING` clause of the `Execute immediate` statement.

Comment: thank you for the reply(+1).. will check accept your answer once i have tested it.. it might take 2-3 days..